# How to find an almost sorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to create a program that will select the fastest sorting algorithm for a particular array of integers. I'm trying to check off the condition "is almost sorted," and was wondering what common practice to find this in the industry is.

Assume that there is a sorted array available to the coder. The two possible solutions I can think of are:

1. Loop through both lists simultaneously. Compare values at the index, find the percentage of correctly placed values. I understand that this is pretty quick (just O(N)), but it can be wildly inaccurate... what if everything is shifted by one space? This algorithm will give 0, but insertion sort will take a single run to do order this.
2. Find how far something is shifted from it's correct position in either direction (w/ wraparound). This seems to be a better solution, but could be pretty slow (O(N^2), since we might have to loop through a sorted list for every unsorted object, which could be corrected A BIT by comparing the value in a while loop).

Are there others? If not, which do I pick?

Thanks!

Comment: TimSort scans through and finds "chunks" of data that are in order.  So for the input `9 4 7 3 1 5 8 7 2 3 6`, it would chunk like this: `9, 47, 3, 158, 7, 6, 236`.  The remainder of the algorithm is irrelevant for your purpose, but you might consider comparing the number/sizes of the chunks to decide if the data is "almost sorted".

Comment: I’m reminded of Python’s sort function, which uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It looks for ordered subsets in the unordered data, and then decides whether to use insertion or merge sort. Finding ordered subsets like that feels like it would be closer to O(N) than O(N^2), and might get you some of the way.

Comment: An algorithm that would do a good job at this would be about as expensive as a bubblesort.  Perhaps even worse.

Comment: The TimSort algorithm is sweet, but it raises the question--what is a large array? Would it be worth at that moment to scan through something that's like, 10 bytes long? Where do we call the line, or is this determined by the data you're working with?

Comment: The beauty of TimSort is that identifying a run is O(n) with little overhead, so it really doesn't matter what size array you're working with.

Comment: Are you trying to measure how "almost sorted" a given array is, or are you trying to generate "almost sorted" arrays?